# How can I erase a 250gb external usb drive with linux partedmagic boot cd

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, boot, usb

I run a dual boot of windows 7 and xp on Dell Optiplex 280 with a Pentium 4 mobo, a CPU of 3 Ghz and 2GB ram. My question is "How do I use the ERASER TOOL in Linux Partedmagic Boot Cd to completely wipe off a 250 GB sata hard drive mounted in an external case.

I have booted my system with the software (Linux Partedmagic Boot Cd), loaded the required files and ejected the cd. A window type interface was displayed at the end of the booting and file loading. The drive in question was displayed among other drives in the system. How do I start the erasing process at this stage. I intend to reformat the drive after the erasing is completed.

Can someone assist me with this task the answers given please.

Thanks.

Radevic

Comment: Have you tried this? http://partedmagic.com/secure-erase/ or this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-disk-format/ . BTW, securely erasing an SSD\thumbdrive is probably very bad for it. IMHO, if at all possible, you should only use the Enhanced version of that.

Answer (score 0):

Low-level reformatting should be sufficient to remove the contents of HDD, **unless** there is information on it of a sensitive nature and you're selling the drive. There are free applications, such as CCleaner Free, http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download, that include drive wiping tools.

Expect to wait some time for complete random overwrite of a HDD to complete.